# Why nginx internal redirect is not happening

Tags: nginx

I'm pretty sure I missed an obvious thing but it's driving me crazy, I need other eyeballs..

I got an application with plugins were sources are organized like:

/app/plugins/foo/www/... that corresponds to my URL http://example.com/plugins/foo/...

I got the following snippet as nginx configuration:

```
location /plugins/foo {
    alias /app/plugins/foo/www;
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
}

location ~* ^/plugins/foo/(.*\.php)$ {
    alias /app/plugins/foo/www/$1;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

It works well for URLs like:

- http://example.com/plugins/foo/style/style.css
- http://example.com/plugins/foo/index.php
- http://example.com/plugins/foo/bar.php

But as soon as I'm trying to reach (front controller pattern):

- http://example.com/plugins/foo/?id=5
- http://example.com/plugins/foo/another/path

I got to download the php file.

According to the logs, the try_files seems to do what is expected but instead of internal redirect to php handler, it server the file as static:

```
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 using configuration "/plugins/foo"
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 rewrite phase: 3
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 post rewrite phase: 4
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 generic phase: 5
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 generic phase: 6
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 generic phase: 7
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 generic phase: 8
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 access phase: 9
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 access phase: 10
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 post access phase: 11
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 try files phase: 12
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 http script var: "/plugins/git/"
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 trying to use file: "/" "/app/plugins/foo/www/"
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 trying to use file: "/index.php" "/app/plugins/foo/www/index.php"
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 try file uri: "/plugins/foo/index.php"
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 content phase: 13
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 content phase: 14
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 content phase: 15
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 content phase: 16
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 content phase: 17
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 content phase: 18
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 http filename: "/app/plugins/foo/www/index.php"
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 add cleanup: 000000000153FF70
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 http static fd: 13
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 http set discard body
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 xslt filter header
2017/01/24 13:29:36 [debug] 20803#0: *6 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

So question is: how to implement my front-end controller pattern in this situation ?

**EDIT**

With

```
location /plugins/foo {
    alias /app/plugins/foo/www;
    try_files $uri /plugins/foo/index.php?$args;
}
```

I got redirected to Core front-controller instead of the plugin ones:

```
2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 using configuration "/plugins/foo"
...
2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 try files phase: 12
2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 http script var: "/plugins/foo/"
2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 trying to use file: "/" "/app/plugins/foo/www/"
2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 http script copy: "/plugins/git/index.php?"
2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 http script var: "group_id=101"
2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 trying to use file: "/index.php?group_id=101" "/app/plugins/foo/www/index.php?group_id=101"
====> ??? 2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 internal redirect: "/index.php?group_id=101"
2017/01/25 13:45:48 [debug] 14086#0: *197 rewrite phase: 1
...
```

Why redirect to `/index.php?group_id=101` when `/app/plugins/foo/www/index.php?group_id=101` is valid ?

Comment: Your `try_files` statement should have one default action. Use `/index.php` or `=404` not both. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details. Also, is `/index.php` or `/plugins/foo/index.php` the correct URI for the front-end controller?

Comment: I updated the question after having modified the `try_files` statement

Comment: I try to avoid using `alias` and `try_files` together because of [this long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). I should probably have commented on that first ;-)

Comment: Oh I see :/ what are my possibilities then ? rewrite ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the [long standing issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) with using `alias` together with `try_files`, you could use an `if` block instead (taking care to [note usage restrictions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)). Note also, that `$request_filename` is used instead of `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` to obtain aliased pathnames.

I have tested this example:

```
location ^~ /plugins/foo {
    alias /app/plugins/foo/www;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^ /plugins/foo/index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^ /plugins/foo/index.php last;
        }
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

- The `^~` modifier make this `location` block take precedence over other `location` blocks at the same level (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)).
- The `rewrite` statement automatically appends arguments (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)).
- The nested `location` block handles PHP files within the aliased scope.
- Always `include fastcgi_params;` *before* using `fastcgi_param` to avoid the latter being silently overwritten by the included file.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! the only thing that I had to modify is `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename last;` on my version of nginx (1.8) it's not valid. Thanks for the snippet and the detailed configuration very much appreciated !

Comment: Oops! How did that get in there? Thanks, answer corrected.