# Nginx doesn't pick the right php-stack in location

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, directory, regex

**UPDATE 28.02.2019**

The problem is the following part inside my server block:

```
        # Don't use `$uri` here, see https://github.com/yandex/gixy/issues/77
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$request_uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
    }
```

Without it, everything finally works as intended. The problem is, that this **is a needed part** for a Wordpress-Multisite Installation to run. Without it, it is not possible to use wp-admin.

After locating the Problem - does anybody has an Idea how to solve it? (beside normal Wordpress installation and separating the forum via proxy as somebody suggested below)

**TL;dr**

I created a location block (/de/forums/) outside of the nginx root folder but the php gets sent to the php compiler inside root so there is a directory mismatch. It wont take the defined php stack inside the new location block. Help!

The location block /de/forums/ works, but just for files, not for php. With php I get a "File not Found" because it uses the main root folder as base and not the new alias.

And I cant figure out how to force nginx to use the more specific php with the right "fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;".

.

**Following situation:**

LEMP Stack with php7.2-fpm

Wordpress Multisite Installation on domain.com - configured to use Subdirectorys. There are two for this domain: domain.com/de/ and domain.com/en/. As you probably guessed for different language versions of a Blog. An example page is domain.com/en/contact-us and a blog post would be domain.com/en/this-is-a-blog-1451

So we have:

```
domain.com/de/
domain.com/en/
domain.com/en/contact-us
domain.com/en/this-is-a-blog-1451
```

We want to add:

```
domain.com/de/forums/
domain.com/en/forums/
```

And this is how the folder stucture looks:

```
/var/www/domain.com/
/var/www/domain.com/html/
/var/www/domain.com/html/index.php #(Wordpress)
/var/www/domain.com/forum-de/index.php #(Xenforo)
/var/www/domain.com/forum-en/index.php #(Xenforo)
/var/www/domain.com/logs/
/var/www/domain.com/ssl/
/var/www/domain.com/wp-config.php
```

So we need to create a location blog for the forum folders. In theory, a more specific location block (/de/forums/) should take precedent over a general / so the block should always point to the forum and not to Wordpress.

**Here is my full server block - with comments for you:**

```
server {

listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name domain.com;

root /var/www/domain.com/html;
error_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/error.log warn;
access_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
index index.php;

location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
# denies all hidden files
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
# Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
# Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";



    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;  
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;                     
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;                   
    }




# indicate locations of SSL key files.
ssl_certificate /var/www/domain.com/ssl/ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /var/www/domain.com/ssl/ssl.key;

# Enable HSTS. This forces SSL on clients that respect it, most modern browsers. The includeSubDomains flag is optional.
# see https://hstspreload.org/
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:P-256:P-384:P-224:P-521;

ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';


# generate by "openssl dhparam -outform PEM -out dhparam2048.pem 2048"
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam2048.pem;
#ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; SEEMS NOT TO WORK WITH CLOUDFLARE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# Enable HSTS. This forces SSL on clients that respect it, most modern browsers. The includeSubDomains flag is optional.
# see https://hstspreload.org/
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

# DO NOT USE!!!!
# DO NOT USEadd_header Public-Key-Pins 'pin-sha256="AKTUELLER-KEY-HASH"; pin-sha256="BACKUP-KEY-HASH"; max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';
# DO NOT USE!!!!


ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:30m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_session_tickets on;
# generate with "head -c 48 /dev/urandom > /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx_ticketkey"
ssl_session_ticket_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx_ticketkey;
ssl_session_timeout 41m;


# resolver conf
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=1200s;
resolver_timeout 5s;



    location ~* \.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
        # gzip_static off;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        break;
    }

    location ~* \.(js)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        break;
    }

    location ~* \.(css)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        break;
    }

    location ~* \.(html|htm|txt)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
        expires 1d;
        break;
    }

    location ~* \.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        break;
    }   




    location ^~ /de/forums/ {
        alias /var/www/domain.com/forum-de/;
        #also tried root
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /de/forums/index.php?$uri&$args;
          #also tried just /index.php?$uri&$args;


    }

location ~  ^/de/forums/(.+\.php)$ { 
    alias var/www/domain.com/forum-de/; 
     #also tried root    
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    #also tried using the full path here
}   


#cloudflare stuff - cut out for shortness sake
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
#many more here

# use any of the following two
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
#real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;



    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)  {
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
        fastcgi_buffers 512 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1m;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 4m;
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 4m;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;


}

}
```

.

**I tried:**

- Using location php as a sub location under /de/forums/
- Using root instead of alias (what is wrong but I got desperate)
- Not using fastcgi.conf link
- Using $request_filename or /var/www/domain.com/html/forum-de/$fastcgi_script_name also /var/www/domain.com/html/forum-de$fastcgi_script_name

  - deleting the / php block, still didn't use the specific to the location /de/forums/

The only thing that was working, was creating an actual folder like /var/www/domain.com/html/de/forums/index.php. But then I get an 404 with wordpress if I want to access /de/ and all the pages there, because of the try_files. I probably could work with if but thats not recommended as far as I read.

Also I can access files with the location blog (jpgs for example) - so the location block works but not the php.

The error message is File not found. So the forum phps getting sent to the php compiler, but there is - I believe - an adress mismatch with the general root and the new location root. I couldn't even access a phpinfo file.

Please help!

**Further readings:**
(aka I found helpful stuff here, but didn't solve my problem)

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808787/file-not-found-when-running-php-with-nginx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827222/file-not-found-nginx-php-fpm
- many more - closed most of the tabs out of frustration...

As most of them suggested, fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename; should fix my problem. BUT... nginx just don't uses my php location with correctly set SCRIPT_FILENAME - it keeps using the "main" php location /

Comment: You should use a nested location block to execute php - like [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/828523/why-nginx-internal-redirect-is-not-happening/828579#828579).

Comment: Thanks, @RichardSmith - but I tried that also. ("Using location php as a sub location under /de/forums/") - did not work. It simply ignores it - and I have no idea why... (opened a different question regarding this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608224/nginx-php-location-block-wrongfully-takes-request )

Comment: Please try using simple `location /de/forums` blocks, without any regex.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's just a combination of wrong `root` and `location` values.

1. change this:

   ```
   location ^~ /de/forums/ {
       alias /var/www/domain.com/forum-de/;
       #also tried root
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /de/forums/index.php?$uri&$args;
         #also tried just /index.php?$uri&$args;


   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   location /de/forums/ {
       root /var/www/domain.com/forum-de/;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /de/forum/index.php?$args;
   }
   ```
2. and change this:

   ```
   location ~ ^/de/forums/(.+\.php)$ { 
       alias var/www/domain.com/forum-de/; 
        #also tried root    
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
       include fastcgi.conf;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
       #also tried using the full path here
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   location ~ ^/de/forums/(.+\.php)$ { 
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
       include fastcgi.conf;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
       fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
   }
   ```
3. If the above solution works for /de/forums/ duplicate and adapt for /en/forums/ .

Additional hint:

If there is more `sever` specific configuration that has to work differently for each app, consider building a solution where the forum is behind a reverse proxy so it can have it's own vhost file.

The logic behind this solution would be to create a separate vhost file for the forum, listening on a 127.0.0.1:8001 (for example) and then in the original vhost file add a proxy_pass for the location /de/forum to http://127.0.0.1:8001.

This way you could have a separate vhost configuration for the forum.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out as soon as possible and report back.

Comment: Thanks again. There are still problems. PHP-Files now load, but files don't. If I want to load an image, there is a not found - this is what the error log says: 2019/02/28 19:05:50 [error] 11545#11545: *394549 open() "/var/www/example.com/html/de/forum/styles/default/xenforo/xenforo-logo2x.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 2a02:myIPhere:2f89, server: domain.com, request: "GET /de/forum/styles/default/xenforo/xenforo-logo2x.png HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/de/forum/install/index.php"

Comment: As I stated in my edit of the question a few minutes ago, I found the part that breaks the functionality. it is: ' if (!-e $request_filename) {
        # Don't use `$uri` here, see https://github.com/yandex/gixy/issues/77
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$request_uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
    }' This is part of the Wordpress-Rewrites. Unfortunately, even if I move the forum to a new vhost (via proxypass), it still breaks when the code is in the main server block. Any ideas why?