# Configure Nginx to run PhalconPHP on a subfolder

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I want to run a PhalconPHP application on a subfolder like this `http://stg.example.org/simon/apps/phalconapp/`

A snippet of my Nginx configuration is as below...

```
location ^~ /simon/apps/phalconapp {

      root /var/www/stg.example.org/simon/apps/phalconapp/public;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;     

      location ~ \.php$ {

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;  
            fastcgi_index  index.php;

            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

      }

  }

  location @rewrite {
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
  }
```

I however, get a *file not found* error when trying to access the application. What could I be doing wrong?

=========
**updated configuration**

```
      location ^~ /simon/apps/phalconapp {

             alias /var/www/stg.example.org/simon/apps/phalconapp/public;
             index index.php index.html index.htm;
             try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

          if (!-e $request_filename) {
              rewrite ^ /simon/apps/phalconapp/public/index.php?_url=/$1 last;
          }

         location ~ \.php$ {

         if (!-f $request_filename) {
              rewrite ^ /simon/apps/phalconapp/public/index.php?_url=/$1 last;
          }

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;  #set port for php-fpm to listen on
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            try_files $uri =404;

            include fastcgi_params;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

      }

  }

  location @rewrite {
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /simon/apps/phalconapp/public/index.php?_url=/$1;
  }
```

**======= Almost working configuration 2**

```
 location ^~ /simon/apps/phalconapp {

     alias /var/www/stg.example.org/simon/apps/phalconapp;
     index index.php index.html;
     try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite; 

    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;  
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include  fastcgi_params;              
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

     }

}

location @rewrite {
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /simon/apps/phalconapp/public/index.php?_url=/$1;
}
```

Comment: Nginx is looking for files at `/var/www/stg.example.org/simon/apps/phalconapp/public/simon/apps/phalconapp`, so you need to use `alias` instead of `root`. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/828523/why-nginx-internal-redirect-is-not-happening/828579#828579). Your `@rewrite` block is also incorrect, the correct URI should be: `/simon/apps/phalconapp/index.php` and not `/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith. I have updated configuration as shown above but the problem persists:-

Comment: You have left the `try_files` statements in. You don't need `try_files` and the `if` blocks, they are both doing the same job. Use `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` when using `alias`.

Comment: I managed to get it to work using configuration 2, above. However, I am unable to get Phalcon to interpret the URI correctly. It should interpret it as `stg.example.org/simon/apps/phalconapp/<module>/<controller>/<action>` , but is instead interpreting  `simon` as the module, `apps` as controller etc. Any clues on how to make Phalcon understand that `/simon/apps/phalconapp/` is just the base uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration has worked for me. I will however appreciate if this answer can be improved by someone who is more knowledgeable with Nginx configurations.

```
  location ^~ /simon/apps/phalconapp {

      alias /var/www/stg.example.org/simon/apps/phalconapp;
      index index.php index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite; 

      location ~ \.php$ {

          fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000; 
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          include  fastcgi_params;              
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     }
}

location @rewrite {
   rewrite ^/simon/apps/phalconapp(.*)$ /simon/apps/phalconapp/public/index.php?_url=$1 ;
}
```