# Location directive in NGINX not working

Tags: nginx

I am trying to open the location of my index.php file for example:

The root folder is:

```
/path/to/my/root/folder
```

The the url a user will use to get to this root folder is:

```
https://sub.mydomain.net/server/client
```

Every time I use this location declaration I get a 404 or forbidden message

```
location /server/client/ {
      alias /path/to/my/root/folder;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
   }
```

I just cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

Of course the index.php is located here:

```
/path/to/my/root/folder/index.php
```

Just for clarification I have declared the following also:

```
index index.html index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
      include conf.d/services/php7.conf;
   }
```

Like I said I just cannot work out what is wrong?

Comment: [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/828523/why-nginx-internal-redirect-is-not-happening/828579#828579) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really post much useful configuration or any error logs. So:

1. Check Nginx or PHP logs
2. Check the permissions of the directory
3. Make sure PHP is configured correctly to work with Nginx.

Comment: I ran php info and it loads correctly with no errors.  Permissions are correct.