# Nginx handle multiple htmls in different for different locations in same server

Tags: nginx, web-server, html

I want to deploy my react app's in `nginx` under the same server, serving different html's for different locations, I have tried below configuration but it din't work for me

```
    server {
  listen 8080;
  # root /usr/share/nginx/build-bms;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP


  server_name _;

  location ^~ /portal1/ {
    root PATH_TO_BUILD_FOLDER_ONE;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    index invalid;
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
    expires      1d;
    autoindex on;
  }

      location ^~ /portal2/ {
    root PATH_TO_BUILD_FOLDER_TWO;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
    index invalid;
    expires      1d;
    break;
    autoindex on;
  }

  location / {
    root PATH_TO_BUILD_FOLDER_THREE;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
    expires      1d;
  }
}
```

Every time only the last one is served

Comment: If the folders are called `portal1` and `portal2`, your `root` statement needs to point to the directory **above**. The path to the file is formed by concatenating the value of `root` with the requested URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

Comment: actually folder name and and paths are different

Comment: You may need to use `alias` and you may want to avoid using `try_files`. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/828523/why-nginx-internal-redirect-is-not-happening/828579#828579) but ignore the bits about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Without being a specialist on nginx i checked my config and would suggest to remove the regex match (if you don't need it) and transform your config to:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  root /usr/share/nginx/build-bms;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP


  server_name _;

  location ^~ /portal1/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/portal1/;
    try_files $uri /index.html index.php;
    index invalid;
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
    expires      1d;
    autoindex on;
  }

  location ^~ /portal2/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/portal2/;
    try_files $uri /index.html index.php;
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
    index invalid;
    expires      1d;
    break;
    autoindex on;
  }
 location  / {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/portal3/;
    try_files $uri /index.html index.php;
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
    expires      1d;
  }
}
```

Instead of using multiple roots i would use alias. But I would always specify a root element for the server and then work with aliases. I would leave that up to the nginx pros to comment.

Comment: tried it, It din't work

Comment: I have edited my answer. It works now. It looks like there is a problem with the try_files directive. when you change try_files $uri /index.html; to try_files $uri /index.html index.php; it works. I am not 100% sure why to be honest but it works.

Comment: I am not using php over here

Comment: i was not using php either but as soon as you add this your config works. What I wanted to say is that your try_files directive doesn’t work. Try this try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

Comment: When i try that try files directive, html is served correctly but assets like js files are being served